# PHP Number Formatting

Tags: php, formatting, numbers

I have been trying all morning but how would I this number `1304583496` to look like this

`13.04583496`

and the same goes for this number

`456604223` to `4.56604223`

There are always 8 numbers to the right.

Comment: if there are always 8 numbers to the right, couldn't you just divide by 100 000 000?

Comment: `echo sprintf('%.8f',$n/100000000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide it with 100000000, or use "pow" function:

```
$number / pow(10, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the official `number_format` method after division to keep your ending zeroes and have your number displayed in a nice manner.

```
<?php
$num = 1304583496; //the number
echo number_format($num/100000000,8,"."," "); //number of decimals = 8, comma seperator is . and thousands seperator is a space here
?>
```

For more information on this function: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp